# TFS check if file exists in build directory

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, xamlbuild

Is there a way to check if a specific .xml file exists in build directory when TFS build runs?

I'm trying to get a Boolean result true/false based on the result found/not found

I tried creating a variable that would store this result (I'm guessing that is the way to do it). However I get an error when trying to use it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I added a new **variable** "dcMatchedFile" - which is a IEnumerable type. Use this dcMatchedFile as "Result" option for FindMatchingFiles" item (see images below)

[image]

[image]

Then you can simply use "If" statement to check Any().

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a script to check if the specific file exist, then check in the script and run as `Pre-build script` in your build process:

e.g.:

```
$Source = $Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY
$filename = "*.xml"

if (!(Test-Path "$Source\$filename"))
{
  Write-Warning "$filename absent from build directory"
  # Write-Error "$filename absent from build directory"
  #exit 1
}
```

Reference [Using Environment Variables in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1035/environment-variables-visual-studio-2013-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

The expression editor uses standard VB.NET, so you can call into `System.IO.File.Exists(path)` to detect whether a file already exists.